# Creating external link to Subscriber Center

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am hoping to link users to the out of the box subscription center but from an external landing page.  I have set up a couple landing pages and I'm at the point where I am able to retrieve a user's Subscriber Key using a web capture form but after they enter this value and I have collected it, I can't seem to activate the subscription link.  I want to have the user enter their subscriber key and once I collect it on the success landing page, I want a link that is able to send them to their Profile and Subscription Center.

Thanks,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to generate a link to the default profile center outside the context of an Email send.  If Landing Pages/Microsites are enabled in the account then a custom page could be created that would mimic the default profile center, but it would require a bit of knowledge on AMPScript.

Comment: Is this still the only way to lead people to their subscription center? I am also looking into a similar solution. We would like people to re-subscribe via a landing page. But I have a problem carrying their subscriber key from outside since they are not provided when they land on the landing page.